{Bug Report} Launchpad SSO no longer functions with Ask ubuntu
For some time now, there's been known issues with Launchpad logins and them simply 'failing' with unknown error messages.
Originally this was with registrations, and users received an error message that said "unknown error".
As of at least three months ago, this issue has evolved into logins getting the same error message.
There is no information client-side for users to resolve this, and despite multiple feature-request and bug-report posts on Meta, it remains unresolved.

This is a master thread that will become the canonical meta post on this issue for tracking


I think I've found a solution to this, and I am now able to login using Launchpad myself.
Turns out one of our requests to the Launchpad API had been missing a / in the URL, which must've worked previously, but now does not.

I havent been able to test - Thanksgiving in the US.  But this probably will solve the problem I bet.  Thanks for looking at it @Connell

I can confirm login works again.  I will test registration at a later time.

We're missing registration via Launchpad / SSO but I'm not sure if that's intentional or not.

Thanks for confirming! Yes, we removed some buttons from the signup page a while ago, to simplify the signup journey as a whole. However, using login where an account does not already exist will create a new account, and I can see there have been successful account creations through the Launchpad over the weekend.

glad to hear.  I've marked this as status-completed now since this is now debugged and working again.
